# Synchronous calculation-heavy method call that doesn't prevent redrawing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Newbie C#/.NET threading question here:

Is it possible to have a synchronous (if that's the right term) method that doesn't return until it has finished some calculation but at the same time doesn't prevent the app from getting redrawn or going to "Not responding".

I guess the answer is probably threads but how does one make them part of a synchronous (if that's still the right term) method call rather than sending an event when done.

As an added requirement the code I'm adding this to does not have any dependencies on Winforms, it is designed to be run from a Console app *or* a Winforms app.

Thanks and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you just want the form to redraw itself, but all controls be locked while your operation is in progress?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to block any user input while your calculation method is being executed. If so, this can be done with [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. Set `Enabled` property of your form to `false`, perform all calculation logic in `DoWork` handler, and reenable form in `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is from System.ComponentModel, which has nothing to do with WinForms.